# My laptop does not power on unless I remove all batteries

Tags: boot, laptop, hardware-failure, asus-laptop

I have an Asus TP300L with Windows 10, updated BIOS. I shut down Windows 10 normally. Then, it does not power on. It seems that there is no any power, it even does not try to boot. Simply, nothing happens. Nothing! It does not matter if I shut down when it has only battery, only AC adapter, or both.

In this state, the only way to power on again the laptop is:

1- Remove AC adapter.
2- Remove battery.
3- **Remove CMOS battery** (Yes! This also is a must) 
4- Wait about 20 seconds 
5- Plug in AC adapter.

Then, the laptop powers on without pressing on button and starts evey thing normally. I can connect battery and remove AC adapter, etc. Every thing works normally!

Here is how LEDs behave:

0- Battery and CMOS battery are removed. There is only AC adapter, and we shut down PC.
Power LED: Off
Battery LED: Continuous orange\

1- Pulse on power button:
Nothing changes

2- Remove AC adapter:
Power LED: Off
Battery LED: Off

3- Immediately plug in AC adapter again:
Power LED: Off
Battery LED: Continuous orange

4- Repeat 2.
5- Wait 30 seconds
6- Plug in AC adapter:
Power LED: On (about 1 second) - Off - Again On 
Battery LED: Continuous orange
7- Then PC starts normally

Why does this happen?
What should I do to power-off power-on normally my laptop?

Comment: Remove CMOS battery (Yes! This also is a must)  .....  Hardware problem - get it serviced. That is the best thing to do.

Comment: You have a power circuit problem on the motherboard, most probably related to a charger chip